# Android app with offline map and database

Tags: android, json, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I made an android application with Google Maps using Maps API v2 and the app is getting the data from JSON generated by PHP from MySQL database. This works great while phone is connected to the internet.
My question is what is the best way to make app usable offline as well. I need just one small area for offline availability and I can download JSON to the phone storage and parse it but the map part is my main concern. As much as I read this won't be possible with Google Maps but what are the alternatives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an **open source Library** available out there named `OSMDroid` which replaces Google MapView classes. It also includes a modular tile provider system with support for numerous `online and offline` tile sources and overlay support with built-in overlays for plotting icons, tracking location, and drawing shapes.
You can follow this [link](http://code.google.com/p/osmdroid/).

OR

You can follow `Mapsforge` which provides free and open software for OpenStreetMap-based applications,offers a library for ad-hoc map rendering on Android devices
Go through this [link](http://code.google.com/p/mapsforge/) for mapsforge usage

Comment: I'll try the OpenStreet Maps, Mapsforge seems nice. Thanks.